# "javax.el.ELException: Property not found on type" on a method expression

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, el, methodexpression

I am using Primefaces 5.2, jsf 2.2 and Tomcat 8 on a Linux server.
This is the line in my xhtml:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadController.complete}" multiple="true"/>
```

The method in the class UploadController:

```
 public void complete(FileUploadEvent fileUploadEvent) {
     UploadedFile item = fileUploadEvent.getFile();
     // ... etc. nothing special, all standard reading
 }
```

If I start up my page in a jetty, everything works fine.

But if I start it up on the linux server with tomcat 8, i got

> javax.el.ELException Property 'complete' not found on type

exception.
I also tried to run my code on my Windows machine in a tomcat 8 (started up by Maven in a cargo container). No problem there.

One step further was to put a parameter for method UploadController.complete :

```
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadController.complete(fileUploadEvent)}" multiple="true"/>
```

...the only way a parameter was excepted (no f:param , f:attribute,... were accepted => same ELException). But then the event "fileUploadEvent" in UploadController is NULL.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a polluted runtime classpath (in other words, a pom with incorrectly scoped dependencies). Do you have any server-specific JAR files in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`, such as `el-api.jar`, etc?

Comment: Problem could be missing jar in your jetty classpath.

Comment: Initially no. As I read that this may help, as there might be an incomplete installation, I tried to add. But no effect. I saw that there is a el-api.jar in the tomcat /lib directory. And it seems to be quite up to date.

Comment: Do not touch the server lib as long as you don't understand how this stuff works. Coming back to the problem, please list all JARs present in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the Maven-produced WAR file.

Comment: There are 127 jar's... . Which to focus?

Comment: There are 127 jar's... . Which to focus? 
But I made another approach: I made my own kubuntu server with my own installation of tomcat 8 and java 1.8. Astonishingly the code seems to run there!
What is the difference?

Original:
- openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal-b14"
- Apache Tomcat Version 8.0.23

My new Server:
- Oracle Java 1.8.0_60-b27
- Apache Tomcat Version 8.0.24